# Where are my js and css links in header?

Tags: headers

I just found out that there are no javascript and css links in my header.php.

```
<?php

/**

 * The Header for our theme.

 *

 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">

 *

 * @package web2feel

 * @since web2feel 1.0

 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title><?php

    /*

     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.

     */

    global $page, $paged;



    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );



    // Add the blog name.

    bloginfo( 'name' );



    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.

    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );

    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )

        echo " | $site_description";



    // Add a page number if necessary:

    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )

        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'web2feel' ), max( $paged, $page ) );



    ?></title>

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<![endif]-->

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

They appear in source view. Can anyone tell me where can I find my f. css and js? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are probably loaded in your **functions.php** file in your theme folder.
Look for lines like:

For CSS: `wp_enqueue_style( ... );`

For JS: `wp_enqueue_script( ... );`

Comment: They should be getting loaded on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook which is run during `wp_head()`